# Calculate $\mathbb{E}(X-Y\mid 2X+Y).$ if $X\sim N(0,a)$ and $Y\sim N(0,b)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, expected-value

> Question: Given that $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables  satisfying $X\sim N(0,a)$ and $Y\sim N(0,b)$ for some $a,b>0$. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ have correlation $\rho.$ 
>   Calculate 
>   $$\mathbb{E}(X-Y \mid 2X+Y).$$

I tried to use the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $\mathbb{E}(A\mid B) = \mathbb{E}(A)$ and uncorrelated implies independence in jointly normal distribution.

So, I attempted to express $X-Y$ as a linear combination of $2X+Y$ and $Z$ where $\operatorname{Cov}(2X+Y,Z) = 0.$
But I am not able to do so.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: If all else fails, you can use that $E(A\mid B=b)=E(A)/f_B(b)$ where $f_B$ is the density of $B$.

Comment: Is $(X,Y)$ jointly normal?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes because linearly combination of normal distributions is jointly normal.

Comment: What I mean is that the quoted problem statement is imprecise; it should mention the joint normality. Linear combinations of jointly normal variables are jointly normal.

Answer (score 2):

Choose $A$ such that $(X-Y)-A(2X+Y)$ is independent of $2X+Y$. For this  need $E[((X-Y)-A(2X+Y)) (2X+Y)]=0$  and this is certainly possible. Now $E(X-Y|2X+Y)=E(((X-Y)-A(2X+Y)+A(2X+Y)|2X+Y)=0+A(2X+Y)$.

Comment: By “independent of,” you mean “uncorrelated with,” right? Is it trivial that uncorrelated here implies mean-independent?

Comment: this is a key property of gaussian vectors indeed.

Comment: It is a nice solution.

Comment: How can you justify the 'this is certainly possible' part? What guarantees the existence of a constant A such that the expectation of the product is 0?

Answer (score 1):

The joint distribution of $(Z_1,Z_2)\equiv(X-Y,2X+Y)$ is $\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$, where
$$
\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}
a+b-2\rho\sqrt{ab} & 2a-b-\rho\sqrt{ab} \\
2a-b-\rho\sqrt{ab} & 4a+b+4\rho\sqrt{ab}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then the [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) of $Z_1$ given $Z_2$ is 
$$
Z_1\mid Z_2=z\sim \mathcal{N}(\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}z,\,\Sigma_{11}-\Sigma_{12}\Sigma_{22}^{-1}\Sigma_{21}).
$$

Answer (score 0):

We use two property:

First: $E(2X+Y|2X+Y)=2X+Y$

Second:  $(X-dY,2X+Y)$ is bi-variate normal(for $d\neq - \frac{1}{2}$), if $Cou(X-dY,2X+Y)=0$ so $X-dY$ and $2X+Y$ are independent(by set $\rho=0$ in bivarite distribution of joint $(X-dY,2X+Y)$
[Correlations_and_independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence)). so $E(X-dY|2X+Y)=E(X-dY)=0$.

$$E(2X+Y|2X+Y)=2X+Y$$

so

$$E(Y|2X+Y)=2X+Y-2E(X|2X+Y)  \hspace{1cm} (1)$$

**For first step let** $\rho=0$

$$cou(X-2\frac{a}{b} Y,2X+Y)=2Var(X)-2\frac{a}{b} Var(Y)=2a-2\frac{a}{b}b=0$$

so since $X-2\frac{a}{b} Y$ and $2X+Y$$ are normal so they are independent.

in hence 
$$E(X-2\frac{a}{b} Y|2X+Y)=E(X-2\frac{a}{b} Y)=0$$

$$E(X|2X+Y)=2\frac{a}{b} E(Y|2X+Y)\hspace{1cm} (2)$$

combine (1) and (2)

$$E(X|2X+Y)=\frac{2\frac{a}{b}}{1+4\frac{a}{b}}\bigg(2X+Y\bigg)$$

$$E(Y|2X+Y)=\frac{1}{1+4\frac{a}{b}}\bigg(2X+Y\bigg)$$

so

$$E(X -Y|2X+Y)=(\frac{2\frac{a}{b}}{1+4\frac{a}{b}}-\frac{1}{1+4\frac{a}{b}})\bigg(2X+Y\bigg)=(\frac{2\frac{a}{b}-1}{1+4\frac{a}{b}})\bigg(2X+Y\bigg)$$

**Now for general case ** $\rho \in[-1,1]$

if $$d=\frac{2a+\rho\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}{b+2\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}} \hspace{1cm} (3)$$

$$cou(X-dY,2X+Y)=2a-db+(1-2d)\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$$
$$=2a+\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}-d(b+2\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b})=0$$

so $$E(X-dY|2X+Y)=E(X-dY)=0$$ and in hence

$$E(X|2X+Y)=dE(Y|2X+Y) \hspace{1cm} (4)$$

Combine (4) and (1)

$$E(Y|2X+Y)=2X+Y-2E(X|2X+Y)=2X+Y-2dE(Y|2X+Y)$$ so

$$E(Y|2X+Y)=\frac{1}{1+2d}\bigg(2X+Y\bigg) \hspace{1cm} (5)$$ and

$$E(X|2X+Y)=dE(Y|2X+Y)=\frac{d}{1+2d}\bigg(2X+Y\bigg) \hspace{1cm} (6)$$

(5) and (6)

$$E(X-Y|2X+Y)=\frac{d-1}{1+2d}\bigg(2X+Y\bigg)$$

$$=\frac{\frac{2a+\rho\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}{b+2\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}-1}{1+2\frac{2a+\rho\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}{b+2\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}}\bigg(2X+Y\bigg)$$

$$=\frac{2a-b-\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}{b+4a+4\rho \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}}\bigg(2X+Y\bigg)$$

**detail for  "@Student"**

I explain now  why I think if $Cou(X-dY,2X+Y)=0$ so $X-dY$ and $2X+Y$ are independent.

**1)**$(X-dY,2X+Y)$ is bi-variate normal for $d\neq \frac{-1}{2}$

I can write
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{bmatrix}
X-dY \\
2X+Y 
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -d \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
Y 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

By [linear-transformation-of-gaussian-random-variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173163/linear-transformation-of-gaussian-random-variable) I think 
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{bmatrix}
X-dY \\
2X+Y 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}

is bi-variate normal.

**2)** Now by [Correlations_and_independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence) I think if $Cou(X-dY,2X+Y)=0$ so $X-dY$ and $2X+Y$ are independent. wikipedia: "In general, random variables may be uncorrelated but statistically dependent. But if a random vector has a multivariate normal distribution then any two or more of its components that are uncorrelated are independent".

Comment: You write that if $X-dY$ and $2X+Y$ are normal and uncorrelated, then they are independent, but this is not true. They are functions of the same underlying $X$ and $Y$ so they are dependent in the general case even if uncorrelated.

Comment: $X$ is marginally normal. Y is marginally normal. any linear combination of them is normal? so $Z=X-dY$ and $W=2X+Y$ are normal. when $cou(Z,W)=0$  so they are uncorrelated but when $Z$ and $W$ are normal too, they are independent.$W$ and $Z$ have a joint density normal,  https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php  , if in joint density normal set $\rho=0$ in hence you get independence.

Comment: Let $A$ be normal and $B\equiv A$ with probability $1/2$ and $-A$ otherwise. $A$ and $B$ are both normal, they are uncorrelated, but not jointly normal, nor independent.

Comment: This is not like that. In this step :  $(X-dY,2X+Y)$ are jointly normal. Now $\rho=0$

Comment: In joint distribution normal , see wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence

Comment: "In general, random variables may be uncorrelated but statistically dependent. But if a random vector has a multivariate normal distribution then any two or more of its components that are uncorrelated are independent. "

Comment: I think you are right if $A$ and $B$ are independent so that $(A,B)$ are jointly normal. But independence is not specified in the question. In my example above, $A-B$ and $A+B$ are uncorrelated but not normal. $A-B=2A$ with probability $1/2$ and $0$ otherwise. $A+B=0$ with probability $1/2$ and $2A$ otherwise. These expressions are not independent, e.g., $P(A-B\leq 0\mid A+B=0) \ne P(A-B\leq 0)$.

Comment: $(X-dY , 2X+Y)$ are jointly normal! by wikipedia : "In general, random variables may be uncorrelated but statistically dependent. But if a random vector has a multivariate normal distribution then any two or more of its components that are uncorrelated are independent. " https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Correlations_and_independence

Comment: Masoud, $X$ and $Y$ are not guaranteed to be independent in the question so $X-dY$ and $2X+Y$ are not guaranteed to be normal, and thus not multivariate normal together. I gave you a related counterexample above.

Comment: do we accept   $(X-dY,2X+Y)$  is bi-variate normal? for $d \neq \frac{-1}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

By @Kavi Rama Murthy answer (and me  in other answer)
$$E(X-Y|2X+Y)=A(2X+Y)$$ 
Now By the Projection property ,$E(X-Y|2X+Y)$ minimized

$$E(X-Y-g(2X+Y))^2$$ [conditional-expectation-as-best-predictor](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71863/problem-with-proof-of-conditional-expectation-as-best-predictor)

I want to find $A$ by minimizing $E(X-Y-A(2X+Y))^2$

$$E(X-Y-A(2X+Y))^2=E((1-2A)X-(1+A)Y)^2$$
$$=E((1-2A)X)^2+E((1+A)Y)^2
-2E((1-2A)X (1+A)Y)2$$
$$=(1-2A)^2E(X)^2+(1+A)^2E(Y)^2
-2(1-2A)(1+A)E(X Y)$$
$$=(1-2A)^2a+(1+A)^2b
-2(1-2A)(1+A)cou(X Y)$$
$$=(1-2A)^2a+(1+A)^2b
-2(1-2A)(1+A)\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$

by derivation $\frac{d}{dA}$ and equal to $0$

$$\frac{d}{dA} E((1-2A)X-(1+A)Y)^2=0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$0=
-4(1-2A)a+2(1+A)b-2(-2)(1+A)\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}-2(1-2A)\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$0=\bigg(
-4a+2b+4\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}-2\rho\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}
\bigg)+\bigg(
8a+2b+4\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}+4\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}
\bigg)A$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$0=\bigg(
-4a+2b+2\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}
\bigg)+\bigg(
8a+2b+8\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}
\bigg)A$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$A=\frac{2a-b-\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}}{4a+b+4\rho \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}}$$